# How can I eliminate a 4-way switch and still have two 3-way switches operating the lights?

Tags: wiring

I have two 3-way switches and one 4-way switch. I eliminate the 4 way and want the two 3-way switches to still turn on and off the lights. So I went up in the ceiling and connected the one switch to the other color to color and I have constant power. The lights will not turn off from the switches. What do I do? The one switch has a feed from power and a switch leg going to the light. The other switch that was going to the 4-way I'm using that 3 wire to connect straight to the other switch where the feed comes in. Both 3 way wires red white black ground. So how can I hook them up so both switches operate the lights?

Comment: Sounds like *maybe* you removed a 3-way, not a 4-way. Can you upload pictures of each of the switches showing all currently connected wires, *plus* the original (removed) switch and the wires that are currently in that box (however they are currently connected).

Comment: You had 4 wires to the 4 pole switch, how were they connected and how did you connect them without the switch? The other 2 switches were working correctly with the 4 way in both conditions.

Comment: Since 3-pole switches are used for industrial 3-phase power, and 4-pole switches are used for generator interlocks for same power, I rather strongly suggest you said "pole" when you meant "way".  I have edited accordingly; if I'm wrong feel free to rollback my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing easier.

[image]

You have 2 travelers.  The 4-way either sends them through straight, or exchanges them.

So take 1 traveler off a brass screw, 1 traveler off a black screw, then splice them together to each other.

Repeat with the other traveler.  And done.